# Magento 2 - How to add additional js files to product page only

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Magento 2 use RequireJS and different approach than version 1. Therefore, if I want to keep using the default theme luna, to extend the product page by adding one javascript file. What is the best way to do?

Should I extend it by creating a new module?

--Update--
After thinking my question above, here, I'm listing what I would like to do in steps as follow. But need help to find the way and solution. Since I'm new to Magento 2, some questions might be too simple to you, please don't mind to give help. Thanks!

1. Create a child theme and use Luma theme as parent. (I'm studying http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html but there are many questions in the detail on how to locate a js file)
2. Magento 2 use RequireJS. What is the best way to put my js file, such as, if I have a js file to trigger some events on product variation changes. And the js file named custom-events.js. Where should I put?

--Update-- 
Created a child theme of luna, ie: named as: Vendor and lunachild:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/lunachild/theme.xml
app/design/frontend/Vendor/lunachild/registration.php
app/design/frontend/Vendor/lunachild/etc/view.xml
```

How to place catalog_product_view.xml in my theme?

Comment: do you want to add js directly to Luma theme?

Comment: No, once there are any Luma theme updated, It won't work well with my customization.  I'm thinking to create a customized template and use Luma as a Parent theme. Therefore, where should I add a js file in a custom child theme? Should use RequireJS method, right? Should create a requirejs-config.js and put my code in there? And what is the best way to put the js into only for the certain block in the Product Page. The block I'm going to put is relevant to variation change, a dropdown on product variation change would trigger an event.

Comment: place catalog_product_view.xml below path

app/design/frontend/Vendor/lunachild/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the better approach is to go through the detail of callback logic:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html

Besides, there is a great tutorial to explain how to init javascript in Magento2 : read this: http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts, and also the Magento Doc: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_init.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add your js throught xml layout. You have to override `catalog_product_view.xml` to local theme.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- /** * Copyright © 2015 Scommerce Mage. All rights reserved. * See COPYING.txt for license details. */ -->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="Custom_Module::custom.js"/>
        <css src="Custom_Module::custom.css"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

Also you can add css or js using require.js and using head.additional block

Comment: So, where should I put this file in my customized child theme? For instance, I created a child-theme (lumachild) under Vendor: ( app/design/frontend/Vendor/lumachild/ ). Already have theme.xml and registration.php created follow with the devdocs.  Where should I put the catalog_product_view.xml to extend the Magento_Catalog in my theme folder?  Thank you.

Comment: Create folder with name "Magento_Catalog" inside your theme. you can create layout and template folder inside the Magento_Catalog.put that file inside the layout folder

lumachild->Magento_Catalog->layout->catalog_product_view.xml